# How do I pass a variable to a function in a table created with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a table with JS and I want to pass the Id of the row to an external function "COPY". I'm having difficulty doing that.

```
for (var i =1; i <= (strln/2); i++) {
// creates a table row
var row = document.createElement("tr");
row.setAttribute("id",""+i+"");
row.setAttribute("onclick",""+'COPY(i)'+"");
}
```

Comment: `row.setAttribute("onclick", "COPY(" + i + ")");`. This is basic string concatenation/manipulation.

Comment: `'COPY(i)'` is in string here.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to do it with string concatenation and `setAttribute` you could try simply like this

```
for( var i=1; i <= ( strln / 2 ); i++ ) {

    var row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.id=i;
        row.onclick=function(e){
            COPY( this.id )
        }.bind( row )
}
```

Comment: force of habit I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

You are currently passing the identifier `i` directly, but that refers to the value after the last iteration. Might simply pass the value directly:

```
 'COPY(' + i + ')'
```

Note that you should actually rather use `.addEventListener`...

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the strings such that variable gets the actual value instead of it becoming a string.

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= (strln / 2); i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.setAttribute("id", i);
  row.setAttribute("onclick", 'COPY("'+i+'")');
}
```